# Post different binary files by curl, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, rcurl

The development environment is ASP.NET(C#) and I develop REST API.
And use curl command for calling the api in integration test.

What I want to know is the following things.

At one request, 
it include two binary data files in an HTTP request body 
and want to post it.

By the way, I know the method to post one binary data file.

The curl commnad is [--data -binary "@filePath"]
The mehod of ApiControlleris [public HttpResponseMessage Post(dyte[] data1)

The binary data of the file are included in variable data1.

It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain the details.

Comment: To someone to be able to explain the details, you should first explain the requirement and implementation details, clearly. Not to mention https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to send two separate files in one response. compress them (zip, rar, gz..a format which your (probably Linux) client can decompress) and change your script to decompress the file after curl stores it.